# Find the highest and lowest value for a time frame in the pine editor

Tags: pine-script, highest

As an absoulutely new beginner I'm experimenting with the pine editor of Tradingview.
I wrote a simple script that plots the difference between ema and dema. Additionally, I want to get the highest and lowest value in the choosen time frame.

Let's assume the highest closed value of a stock is $120,3 and the lowest closed value is $49,41 in the 6M time frame. I want to plot these two horizontal lines that represents all-time high and all-time low for a specific time frame.

```
//@version=4
study(title="Test")

biggest(series) =>
    max = 0.0
    max := nz(max[1], series)
    if series > max
        max := series
    max

smallest(series) =>
    min = 0.0
    min := nz(min[1], series)
    if series < min
        min := series
    min

fast = 14, slow = 50

length = input(fast, minval=1)
src = input(close, title="Source")
e1 = ema(src, length)
e2 = ema(e1, length)
dema = 2 * e1 - e2

band4 = hline(0, "Upper Band", color=#ff0000)

fastEMA = ema(close, fast)
slowEMA = ema(close, slow)
test = (dema - slowEMA)//(high1-low1)
plot(test,color=color.white)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
//@version=4
study(title="Help (Test)")

biggest(series) =>
    max = 0.0
    max := nz(max[1], series)
    if series > max
        max := series
    max

smallest(series) =>
    min = 0.0
    min := nz(min[1], series)
    if series < min
        min := series
    min

fast = 14, slow = 50

length = input(fast, minval=1)
src = input(close, title="Source")
e1 = ema(src, length)
e2 = ema(e1, length)
dema = 2 * e1 - e2

band4 = hline(0, "Upper Band", color=#ff0000)

fastEMA = ema(close, fast)
slowEMA = ema(close, slow)
test = (dema - slowEMA)//(high1-low1)
plot(test,color=color.black)

//[ADDON]
period = input("6M", "Period hi/lo detect", input.resolution) //  Six Months

var hi = 0.0
var lo = 10e10
var br = 0
var lnhi = line.new(na, na, na , na)
var lnlo = line.new(na, na, na , na)

if change(time(period))
    hi := test
    lo := test
    br := bar_index
    lnhi := line.new(br, hi , br, hi, color=color.red, width=2)
    lnlo := line.new(br, lo , br, lo, color=color.green, width=2)
    float(na)
else
    hi := max(test, hi)
    lo := min(test, lo)

line.set_xy1(lnhi, br, hi)
line.set_xy2(lnhi, bar_index, hi)
line.set_xy1(lnlo, br, lo)
line.set_xy2(lnlo, bar_index, lo)
```

Your plot `test` with the ABSOLUTE HIGHEST and LOWEST value for six months time frames.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `highest()` and `lowest()` functions.

So using your example you can add the highest and lowest bands as follows:

```
//@version=4
study(title="Test")

hiloperiod = 200 // track highest/lowest of the last 200 periods
fast = 14, slow = 50

length = input(fast, minval=1)
src = input(close, title="Source")
e1 = ema(src, length)
e2 = ema(e1, length)
dema = 2 * e1 - e2

band4 = hline(0, "Upper Band", color=#ff0000)

fastEMA = ema(close, fast)
slowEMA = ema(close, slow)
test = (dema - slowEMA)//(high1-low1)
plot(test,color=color.white)

// Plot the highest and lowest values for the last hilo period.
hi=highest(hiloperiod)
lo=lowest(hiloperiod)
plot(hi, color=color.green, linewidth=2)
plot(lo, color=color.green, linewidth=2)
```

Using it on the bitcoin price for example yields this graph. Notice how the green lines move to represent the highest and lowest prices for that timeframe

[image: bitcoin price with high and low tracking]

Comment: thanks, but I only want to plot the ABSOLUTE HIGHEST and LOWEST value. Therefore, in my case two horizontal lines that represents allt-time high and all-time low for a specific time frame

Comment: hi, i have the same problem to plot only the highest and the lowest value on all the period.