# How to get the highest value between 2 points?

Tags: pine-script

I want to get the highest point between 2 entries (ex. between 2 ema crosses, like the image example).
It's over my head, I tried with `barssince()` without luck.
Any help would be welcomed!

```
//@version=4
study("My Script", overlay = true)

ema1 = ema(close, 20)
ema2 = ema(close, 50)
plot(ema1)
plot(ema2, color = color.yellow)

buy = crossover(ema1, ema2)
sell = crossunder(ema1, ema2)

highest_buy = highestbars(high, barssince(buy))

plot(highest_buy)
```

[image]

Comment: Look at my answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65765086/converting-series-integer-to-integer-in-pinescript/65805241#65805241). If you can't find a solution on your own, I will try to help you.

Comment: @AnyDozer thank you, it's very similar with Bjorn's answer, you have a good example, I managed to recreated it from your example with success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When `sell` signal appears `highest_buy` is equal `na` and the label is not displayed. It is necessary to take the values on the previous bar.

```
//@version=4

study("Help prof (My Script)", overlay = true)

var bool    track       = false
var float   highest_buy = na

ema1 = ema(close, 20)
ema2 = ema(close, 50)

buy  = crossover(ema1, ema2)
sell = crossunder(ema1, ema2)

if buy
    track := true
else if sell
    track := false

highest_buy := track ? max(nz(highest_buy), high) : na

plot(ema1)
plot(ema2,        color=color.yellow)
plot(highest_buy, color=color.purple, style=plot.style_linebr)

buy_entry = valuewhen(buy, close, 0)
plot(buy_entry, color = buy_entry == buy_entry[1] and ema1 > ema2? color.lime :na)

if sell 
    label1 = label.new(bar_index, highest_buy[1], text=tostring(highest_buy[1] - buy_entry[1]) , style=label.style_label_down, color=color.black, textcolor=color.white)
```

[image]

Comment: More than perfect, I was quite close, thank you!

Comment: Ok, I know this became frustrating, but why it's plotting to 0 if I'm trasformin all syntaxes to get the lowest point? From `highest_buy := track ? max(nz(highest_buy), high) : na` in `highest_buy := track ? min(nz(highest_buy), low) : na` ...

Comment: Change `var float   highest_buy = na` in `var float   highest_buy = 10e10`

Comment: Still at value 0

Comment: Add a new question

Comment: In the operator `if` the conditions `buy` and `sell` are reversed?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228005/discussion-between-edward-and-anydozer).

Answer (score 1):

Continuous plot:

```
//@version=4
study("My Script", overlay = true)

var bool    track       = false
var float   highest_buy = na

ema1 = ema(close, 20)
ema2 = ema(close, 50)

buy  = crossover(ema1, ema2)
sell = crossunder(ema1, ema2)

if buy
    track := true
else if sell
    track := false

highest_buy := track ? max(nz(highest_buy), high) : na

plot(ema1)
plot(ema2,        color=color.yellow)
plot(highest_buy, color=color.purple, style=plot.style_linebr)
```

Plot latest occurrence only:

```
//@version=4
study("My Script", overlay = true)

var bool    track       = false
var float   highest_buy = na
var int     bar_buy     = na
var int     bar_sell    = na
var line    hline       = line.new(na, na, na, na, extend=extend.both, color=color.purple)

ema1 = ema(close, 20)
ema2 = ema(close, 50)

buy  = crossover(ema1, ema2)
sell = crossunder(ema1, ema2)

if buy
    track := true
    bar_buy := bar_index

highest_buy := track ? max(nz(highest_buy), high) : na

if sell
    track := false
    bar_sell := bar_index
    line.set_xy1(hline, bar_buy,  highest_buy)
    line.set_xy2(hline, bar_sell, highest_buy)


plot(ema1)
plot(ema2,        color=color.yellow)

bgcolor(buy  ? color.green : na, transp=80)
bgcolor(sell ? color.red   : na, transp=80)
```